# Allowing the browser to request a value from my app

Tags: javascript, android, android-intent, intentfilter

I'm new to Android and learning about intent-filters. I've set up an intent-filter and an anchor on an html page to launch my app from the browser and now I want to return a value to the browser.

I have a website, and when the user navigates there using the android browser AND has my app installed (but for whatever reason the user chooses not to use the app), I want to use whatever mechanisms are available (i.e. JavaScript) to call into my app and return a string value.

I've been able to use an intent api to request an object from another app w/o showing any UI. I'm just not sure how this was done or if this method could be used from a browser.

Posting the value to the server won't work. I could consider opening a new browser with the value in the query string, but this is a poor UX and poses a risk to our security model.

Comment: I don't know of anything the way you're describing, but have you tried sending your server a value when the Intent-filter is handled by your app? IE. You know there's in the app and they came through the intent-filter you had set up, so then you can post some data to your server directly through the app

Comment: you could maybe have the app open a URL containing the return value. might not be a good idea tho.